# Java String to Date to Different String format

Tags: java, angularjs, datetime

I am using an `angularjs date time picker` that when used directly is in the format of:

```
2016-01-18T05:00:00:000Z
```

this angularjs format works for me, but later I store it off and when retrieved it is in the format of:

```
Mon Jan 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Which does not work for me. So I need to take the non-working String representation of the date (second one), and convert it into my working representation (first one). I would imagine I have to convert it like `String > Date > Diff String`, but looking at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) I don't even see where the `T` comes from in `2016-01-18T05:00:00:000Z`

Comment: It's just a literal. _Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote._

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what am I trying to *avoid interpretation* of?

Comment: The `-T` part of the target format. It'll be added literally during `format`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first format is ISO 8601 Time zone. Try use the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Comment: does `EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ '('zzzz')'` match the second format correctly (`Mon Jan 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`)?